# Symfony2 - Cannot set password form field to type "password"

Tags: php, symfony

I have build a form class to generate a form that will allow a user to type in a new password twice in order to change it.

code:

```
<?php

namespace UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackValidator;

class PasswordType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('password', null);
        $builder->add('confirmPassword', null, array('label' => 'Confirm Password', 'property_path' => false));
        $builder->addValidator(new CallbackValidator(function($form)
            {
                if($form['confirmPassword']->getData() != $form['password']->getData()) {
                    $form['confirmPassword']->addError(new FormError('Passwords must match.'));
                }
            }));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'UserBundle\Entity\User',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'password';
    }
}
```

Now, this class works pretty well, BUT my issues is that when I set the first password field to type "password" I get this error:

> Circular reference detected in the "password" type (defined in class "UserBundle\Form\Type\PasswordType").

And I cannot leave it set to "null" as it will use a normal text input field, which is not ideal.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be from using "password" as the getName() value.

Before:

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'password';
}
```

After:

```
public function getName()
{
    return 'changePassword'; // basically anything other than 'password'
}
```

I changed this to "pass" and now I can use "password" to set the type, i.e.

```
$builder->add('password', 'password');
```

Answer (score 4):

You defined PasswordType form type field. Then you added a field of Password type inside it. That caused another call to PasswordType::buildForm() to add another field of this type and it goes forever.

The solution is to rename your password type to something like 'userpassword' or you can use [`repeated`](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/repeated.html) field type instead. It will add two fields and do comparison validation of thier values.

Comment: The value "password" in the first option of $builder->add() is the field name, not it's type.

Comment: @MrPablo i know. "set the first password field to type "password"" so you set the second argument which is its type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *repeated field type* instead of your solution, see http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

Comment: Looked at using repeat, but there are currently issues with the form errors it produces, so I am staying away form it for now :) I figured out the answer, but I cannot post it for 8 hours, but here it is: The issue seems to be from using "password" as the getName() value.

I changed this to "pass" and now I can use "password" to set the type, i.e.
    $builder->add('password', 'password');

Comment: @MrPablo that's what i told you in my answer ;p

Comment: @MrPablo That's exactly what meze said ;o

Comment: Sorry, but it had nothing to do with the $builder->add() part. Meze said I had defined the field type as password, but if you check, it is set to "null". The issues was getName(). Using getName() as "password" was causing the problem, I changed that and THEN I changed $builder->add('password', null) to $builder->add('password', 'password') and it worked. Meze was wrong.